# Adding content and float outer screen on body

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, css-float

Is there a way to scroll horizontally if content is going beyond 100% width?

For example: I have a blank page and it continuous adding divs to the container with ajax.

CSS for the parent div:

```
position:absolute;
top: 50px;
left:240px;
height: calc(100% - 50px);
width:calc(100% - 240px);
background: #F1F1F8;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: auto;
```

The child divs that are added with ajax:

```
position: relative;
height:100%;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
width:auto;
min-width: 300px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
background-color:#282D32;
float:left;
```

If I add more divs it breaks the line, but I want a scrollbar to scroll horizontally.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `white-space:nowrap` takes no effects with floating elements for the layout. You can set the child divs to `display:inline-block` instead.

If you only need the horizontal scrollbar, you can do `overflow-x:auto` + `overflow-y:hidden`.

```css
.parent {
  font-size: 0; /*remove whitespace*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 240px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  background: #F1F1F8;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.child {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: #282D32;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #464E55;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping all of the elements inside another div that has infinite width (999999px or expand it every time you add a new element). That way parent div has fixed width (100% - 240px from what I can see in your css) and it has overflow: auto (or you can put overflow: scroll), and this new wrapper around all of the items will be wider than parent so there will actually be content to scroll. The way you did it your 5th item gets to the edge of parent div and it can't go anywhere else than in a new line.